# How to undo git add (remove all files from staging area)?

Tags: git

Say I put a lot of files in the staging area (or index), but now I want to undo this, removing all the files (it doesn't matter if they get deleted, they were all wrong). I read somewhere I should do a `git reset`, but since I haven't commited those files yet, wouldn't that actually delete my previous commit, which was actually correct, and which code I'm currently trying to preserve?

In my understandment, that would only work if I had actually commited these changes, so that this commit would then be deleted and the HEAD would now be the previous commit. What am I missing here? I know there are similar posts in here but the answers always point to a git reset, and that's precisely what I don't understand.

Comment: Just a `git restore --staged .` from the root folder of your directory for unstaging all files and then manually `git add <file(s)>` should be enough to stage relevant files, then commit as needed. Use [glob paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) if familiar to ease your common-pattern selections.

Answer (score 1):

`git reset` will restore the staging area to reflect the current commit.  (HEAD).  `git status` will report that there are no changes staged. This, in effect, undoes all your `git add` and `git rm --cached` commands you may have done.

`git reset` is a complicated command that can do many things.  If you use `git commit <commit-id>`, then the HEAD will be moved to that commit--possibly losing the most recent commits, if there are no other refs (branches, tags) pointing to the most recent commits.

`git reset` without specifying a commit will not move the HEAD.

`git reset`  is the same as `git reset --mixed` which restores the staging area to the current commit

`git reset --hard` will restore the staging area, as well as the working tree to the current commit, losing any local uncommitted changes you have may have.

`git reset --soft` will not change your staging area or working tree.  In fact this command will not make any changes at all.  `git --reset soft` is usually used with a commit-id to change the HEAD, current commit, to a different one, while retaining your working tree and staging area exactly as it is.

Answer (score 1):

With your situation, use **git reset** is not best choice. The simple way is use one of two way below.

1. if the files which you want to delete from staging area (index/cache), it was tracked on some commits before

```
git restore --staged <filenames> or git rm --cached <filenames>
```

2. other cases

```
git restore --staged <filenames>
```

3. optional, maybe you still can use  **git reset**, but really carefully, because it's easy to accident

```
git reset <filename>
```

Comment: Note that there is a difference between `git restore --staged <filenames>` and `git rm --cached <filenames>`.  After a `git restore`, the new commit will have the files unchanged from the previous commit. After a `git rm`, the new commit will delete those files; they will not be there if the new commit is checked out.

Comment: who do you mean? , with the above situation, I don't care about git commit,  just undo git add

Comment: after undo git add, what files the next commit contains, is no longer issue of this question. Because we have to control the files we want commit.\

Comment: @lilnoob, if it resolve your problem or useful for you, please upvote or accept it

Answer (score -2):

use the following git command :

> git rm --cached

Comment: The problem with `git rm --cached` is that it literally removes all files from the staging area.  What this means is that if a commit is created, it will have no files. I don't think this is what lilnoob wants.

Comment: For clarification:  `git rm --cached .` will remove all files from the staging area.  `git rm --cached file1` will remove file1.  This is not the same as undoing `git add file1`, as you will not have the original file1, you will have no file1 at all.